# How can you make a function go to another function?

Tags: python, input

So I have this game:

```
import sys

def Start():
    print("Hello and welcome to my first Python game. I made it for fun and because I am pretty bored right now.")
    print("I hope you enjoy my EPIC TEXT GAME")

play = input("do you want to play? (Y / N) ")

if play == "Y":
    game()

if play == "N":
    sys.exit()

def game():
    print("That's pretty much what I've done so far! :P -- yea yea, it's nothing -- IT IS!. Bye now")
    input("Press enter to exit")
```

If I type "Y" I want to go to game(). It doesn't.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you perhpas write "y" (lower-case `y`?)

Comment: Also, Python version is very important, i assume Python3.X..

Comment: Assume it's python 3 because of print function, so input() is ok here

Answer (score 4):

You have defined `game` after you tried and use it. You need to define functions, variables, etc. before you use them.
Also, your code only matched on upper case `Y` and not lower case `y`. To make all input upper case, you should use the `.upper()` method on it
Change the code to:

```
def game():
    print("That's pretty much what I've done so far!")
    input("Press enter to exit")

if play.upper() == "Y":
    game()
elif play.upper() == "N":
    sys.exit()
```

It is usually best form to not have any global code, and instead include it in a `main` function if the python code is being run as the main. You can do this by using:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Start()
```

And then put all that global code into the `Start` method.
Again, make sure you declare before you use.

Comment: No problem. you should consider looking at [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/) to get all this juicy knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the [input()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) function which executes the input as a command immediately after reading it from stdin.

You probably want to use [raw_input()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) which will simply return what the user entered

Comment: This is python 3.0 which does not have `raw_input` (you can tell by the print statement).

Comment: The print function is valid in Python 2.7 as well. I didn't know about the input/raw_input change in 3.x. Thanks.